# Request.Files throws object reference not set - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I have a strange problem.

I want to save an uploaded image to a folder from my project.

Here is the code from the controller:

```
 ......

 if (Request.Form["InputFile"] != null)
  {
     string directory = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFiles/");
     var file = Request.Form["InputFile"];
     string filename = fileService.GetFileName(directory, Request.Form["InputFile"]);
     Request.Files[0]?.SaveAs(filename);
 }
```

when the debugger get to this line:

```
 Request.Files[0]?.SaveAs(filename);
```

the application throws the `Object reference not set` error, for the `Request.Files`.

In the view I have added the

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form" }))
```

Here is the code in view:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
     <div class="col-md-8">
      @Html.TextBox("uploadFile", "", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" , @onChange= "readURL(this);" })
       </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="fileUpload btn btn-success form-control">
       <span>Browse</span>
       @Html.TextBox("InputFile", "", new { type = "file", @class = "upload", @id = "uploadBtn" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The InputFile in the model:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase InputFile { get; set; }
```

Can you please advise what to try in order to save the selected image to the folder?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the overload of `BeginForm()` that adds route values, not html attributes. If you inspect the html you are generating you will see that the `<form>` element does not contain a `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Change the code to (substitute your controller and action names)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form" }))
```

In addition, your model contains a property which is `HttpPostedFileBase`, so it is not necessary to use either `Request.Form["InputFile"]` or `Request.Files[0]`. Instead just use (assumes the parameter for the model in your POST method is named `model`)

```
if (model.InputFile != null && model.InputFile.ContentLength > 0) {
    .... // save file
```

I also recommend using the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputFile, new { type = "file", @class = "upload" })`
```